# Python string.Template removes double $

Tags: python

I am using `string.Template.safe_substitute(...)` to replace keys within a string by a given dictionary. Those strings may contain double `$` character which I don't want to be replaced because they are not keys.

Given the following example:

```
>>> Template("foo$$bar").safe_substitute({"key":"val"})
'foo$bar'
```

I actualy expected the string to be not changed because `key` in the dictionary does not match any `$key` in the given string and the documentation for that function says :

> the original placeholder will appear in the resulting string intact. Also, unlike with substitute(), any other appearances of the $ will simply return $ instead of raising ValueError.

But instead one of the `$` was removed. Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings) says:

> $$ is an escape; it is replaced with a single $.

If you want to keep 2 `$` you need to escape it twice:

```
>>> Template("foo$$$$bar").safe_substitute({"key":"val"})
'foo$$bar'
```

Comment: Oh man, I always read the function definition but always missed the upper part.

Answer (score 3):

The `string.Template` class uses a regular expression internally to parse the template arguments: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/string.py#l54

It seems the regular expression is just not made to support those double dollar signs (which is understandable, since they are reserved template tokens).

One workarround solution would be to replace your double dollars with something very unlikely to be in your string:

```
Template("foo$$bar".replace("$$", "DOUBLE_DOLLAR")).safe_substitute(...).replace("DOUBLE_DOLLAR", "$$")
```

Answer (score 2):

The parser sees `$$` and replaces it with `$` before it sees that `$bar` is not a valid key. This makes the processing of `$$` consistent in situations where it isn't strictly necessary